# PHP remote access MSSQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, xampp

I was trying to use php to remote connect to MSSQL database in other server. But at the end it show error

```
Warning: mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]: Unable to connect to server: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx in xxxxxxx
```

Here is my code

```
    <?php
$myServer = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
$myUser = "user";
$myPass = "password";
$myDB = "database";

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
  or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");

//select a database to work with
$selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
  or die("Couldn't open database $myDB");
  ?>
```

I have try the login with microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and it can work and login so I don't that having problem with the allow remote connection access.

Btw.. I just access it from XAMPP Localhost. I'm not sure is this effect or not.

Thank you in advanced for whose help.

Comment: is the extension installed? Check your configurations file

Comment: you mean this --> extension=php_mssql.dll.. Yes it have..

Answer (score 0):

First guess: 
Your SQL-Server is not listening to TCP/IP. Enable that protocol in configuration manager. Restart the server process.

Second guess:
A firewall is blocking the access. Enable access to TCP Port 1433.

Third guess:
driver problems
mssql driver need that special version of the ntwdblib.dll.
Depending on you php version it's not there.

Better switch to the new driver "sqlsrv".
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

Comment: hi, Due to already have other server connect to the database already so i dun think first and second problem... for third i also change the version that people who suggest online.. Due to client server php version are too low i cannot upgrade to sqlsrv.